# 301 Redirect Specific Pages in Nginx BEFORE Redirecting Entire Domain/Catch All

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have thousands of pages to 301 redirect in nginx. I can achieve this using

```
return 301 https://www.newdomain.com$request_uri;
```

However, there is approximately 6 pages that I would like to redirect to a changed slug/path on the new domain, eg

```
   location /old-path/ {
   rewrite ^ https://www.newdomain.com/newpath/ permanent;
   }
```

I have tried but can't see to work out how to redirect these 6 first, specifically, and then have the catch all rule apply to everything else.

At the moment I am redirecting on the old domain using the catch all only, and then have 301s on the new domain changing the 6 posts to the new paths (2 redirects total for these 6 posts).

I would like to achieve the above not only to reduce the redirects to 1 for these 6 pages, but also because I want to redirect one of the 6 pages to a new path on the new domain, but it's old path still exists as a (new) page on the new domain too (therefore I need to redirect it on the old domain, not on the new one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directives of the [rewrite module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) are executed in order, so the entire process can be accomplished with `rewrite` and `return` directives alone, without wrapping them within `location` blocks. For example:

```
server {
    ...
    rewrite ^/old-path/ https://www.newdomain.com/newpath/ permanent;
    rewrite ^/...       https://www.newdomain.com/.../     permanent;
    return 301          https://www.newdomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

If you wrap the `rewrite` statements within `location` blocks, then the `return` statement must also be wrapped within a `location` block. For example:

```
location / {
    return 301 https://www.newdomain.com$request_uri;
}
location /old-path/ {
    rewrite ^ https://www.newdomain.com/newpath/ permanent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @richard, this seems to have worked! I've noticed though that if I have rules such as:

`rewrite ^/archive-page/ https://www.newdomain.com/new1/new2/ permanent;rewrite ^/archive-page/old1/ https://www.newdomain.com/new3/ permanent;`

Then everything after the /archive-page/ such as /archive-page/old1/ will get redirected to the first rule also. Is there any way around that?

Comment: Hi again, I think I fixed the above with:

    `if ($request_uri = "/archive1/") { rewrite ^ https://www.newdomain.com/new1/new2/ permanent; }
    if ($request_uri = "/archive1") { rewrite ^ https://www.newdomain.com/new1/new2/ permanent; }` I implemented that and everything after /archive1/ such as /archive1/324324/ for example are redirected properly as per my other rules

Comment: You can make the regular expression as specific as required, and more specific regular expressions should be placed before less specific ones. If you want an exact match, add a trailing `$` to the regular expression.

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand that last part - at the moment the order of the rules in the conf file is: 1. if statement rules (2 of them) 2. rewrite rules (about 60) 3. the return rule (1 rule). Should I change that order? Also I think you are saying I could optimise things with the `$` but again sorry I don't really know where to put that specifically. Does it replace the `""` in my if statement? Or do I not need the if statement (and can just do the normal rewrite rule) if I use the `$` - so it would be `rewrite ^/archive1/$ ... permanent;`

Comment: Also, could all these rules (especially the if statements I guess) impact nginx/web server performance in any meaningful way?

Comment: `if ($request_uri = "/archive1/")` is the same as `^/archive1/$` when written as a regular expression. So your `if` block could be replaced by `rewrite ^/archive1/$ https://www.newdomain.com/new1/new2/ permanent;`